# Injecting stringified JSON into script

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a defined `myfile.js` that contains a JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  key: 'This can\'t be true',
},
```

I'm trying to inject a `script` tag into an HTML, doing something like this

```
const object = require('./myfile.js');
const stringified = JSON.stringify(object);
const inject = `<script>window.parsed = JSON.parse('${stringified}');<script />`
```

When I try to open the HTML file with the injected script it logs an JSON-related error – that it had problems parsing it. When I however remove the `\'` from the sentence, there are no problems at all – see below:

```
module.exports = {
  key: 'This cant be true',
},
```

My question is – how can I use the apostrophes and still be able to inject this into the script? Or maybe there is some other way I should think about when passing JSON to HTML?

Comment: It's failing because the result is `"<script>window.parsed = JSON.parse('{\"key\":\"This can't be true\"}');<script />"` - the `'` is unescaped in a string *delimited by `'`*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You mean like: `<script>window.parsed = JSON.parse("${stringified}");</ script>`?

Comment: Stringify it again - `\`<script>window.parsed = JSON.parse(${JSON.stringify(stringified)});</ script>\``

Comment: Oh it definitely does! Thanks a lot!